# How to manually add an artwork to the iTunes Artwork directory?

Tags: itunes, macos, music, hacking

I would like to add an artwork to an album which has files saved in `.wav` format. I know that it is not possible to attach an artwork to a wave file, so I'm trying to add a standalone artwork.jpg file to the album in iTunes.

I found out that:

- it is not possible to attach an artwork to a track or an album directly
- placing an `artwork.jpg` file in the album's directory doesn't work.
- I learnt from other sources like [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1126843?start=0&tstart=0) that there iTunes saves artworks somewhere in the Album Artwork folder (probably here: `/Users/user/Music/iTunes/Album\ Artwork`).

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to add an artwork manually somewhere in that `Album Artwork` folder?
2. Is there any other hacky way to make iTunes actually load an artwork to an album in `.wav` format?

*Note: The album is not available on the iTunes store, so the album hasn't got the official artwork which could be downloaded by iTunes on its own.*

---

*Note 2: the traditional way of adding an artwork using `Get info` does not work for `.wav` files.*

---

#### Major update:

It turns out that **it is possible to add an artwork to any album in iTunes.** The format doesn't matter.

There is one more problem however: it is not possible to add an artwork to an album which has only one track.

Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find the track [or the entire album] in iTunes, select it then hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>  to get info.
Select the Artwork tab then drag your picture from Finder into there.

Unfortunately, this appears to work for just about any format *except* WAV.
This also applies to an overall 'album' artwork added to the folder rather than files. It will only work if they are not all WAVs.

I'd suggest perhaps converting to AIF, which would be a completely lossless conversion.

Comment: Noo, it does not work for wave files, since you cannot add an artwork to them

Comment: You're right - it used to; the file was added to iTunes rather than the file - I'm testing… will tweak answer if I find any option...

Comment: Ahhh, you can add to an AIF, but not a WAV. I'd just convert one to the other; it's completely lossless, not even really a conversion as such.

Comment: Yeah, I've considered it already. I was just thinking whether there is a way to put an artwork file in such place that iTunes would automatically load it as an album cover (and not as an artwork of a track itself).

Comment: If you have it categorised as an 'album' in iTunes, then you can add album artwork in the same way by getting info on the 'album' itself - it then doesn't matter what the files within it are [tested on a composite 'album' of MP3, WAV & AIF] It doesn't add it to WAVs, but it does 'claim' that is the artwork for the 'album'

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. The funny thing is the album I am trying to add artwork to is a single - there is only one track. As a result **iTunes treats it as a single track although it has its own album name**. Is there a way to add an artwork to **a single track album**?

Comment: Ugh… no, if the single track is a WAV but yes, if it's anything else; tested empirically…  AIF looks the way to go, for Apple, WAV is a Win format really. [I haven't tested 'advanced' WAV formats, BWAV etc - I don't really put those in iTunes

Answer (score 1):

I do that all the time..
Wav. / Aiff. file - Get info. 
Open the .jpeg file
Copy <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and Paste <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> into the artwork.

[image]

Works great!

Comment: doesn't work with wav files

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an mp4 file. So, i pressed right mouse on the file in Itunes, and selected to Create ACC version. After this, I deleted the mp4 file. Then, I could right mouse, get info, and manually add my artwork.

Comment: Be sure to actually answer the question asked by the OP; if you want to add a different question you can do so (and answer it yourself), but this looks like a comment, which you will be able to leave when you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: It is a way around but it is not what I am looking for. I want my file to be in the WAVE format, not ACC.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did, since while most of my iTunes albums are recorded as high-quality VBR .mp3's, there are some albums I want to copy as .wav in order to maintain the CD quality while listening through a good sound system.

I go to the last track on the album, right-click on it and select "Create .mp3 version." Once that's done, I right-click on the newly created .mp3 version and add the artwork there as normal. It's now applied to the whole album in iTunes (but will only show up on your iPod or iPhone when playing the single .mp3 file unfortunately.)

Annoying that you have to perform this work-around, but it does at least clean up any missing artwork in iTunes itself. Note you have to keep the spare .mp3 file in the album after adding the artwork, otherwise the apple nazis will once again force removal of the artwork. Sigh.

HTH.

Comment: As in my original answer, just use AIFs, as the artwork seems to 'stick' for them, iirc. There is no real difference between AIF & WAV, sonically. AIF is actually what CDs are recorded in.